# How can I make a post request to wordpress from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, express

This is what I have and it doesn't work. I need to update an acf-field at wordpres from a nodejs application:

```
var username = 'username';
var password = '****';
var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + 
password).toString('base64');


var clientServerOptions = {
uri: 'http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
body: JSON.stringify({action:'microserviceOnline', update : '1', field : 'wschannel_status', micro: '138'}),
method: 'POST',  
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': auth
 }
} 


request(clientServerOptions, function (error, response) { 
    console.log(response);
});
```

This is what I have in my functions.php in theme folder:

```
function microserviceOnline() {
  global $post;

  // Update the field 
  update_field($_POST['field'], $_POST['update'], $_POST['micro']);

  die(':)');  

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_microserviceOnline',  'microserviceOnline' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_microserviceOnline','microserviceOnline' );
```

Comment: Can you explain further what doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't update the wschannel_status acf-field :(

Answer (score 1):

You're sending JSON, but then trying to access it as though you'd sent a URI-encoded form (`$_POST['field']` and such, see [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)). That's a bit like speaking English to a vending machine expecting you to press a button to choose your item.

Either send URI-encoded form data, or process what you receive on the server as JSON.

Comment: this is what I get from console.log(response)
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request',